# My application wont allow me to open any other application

Tags: android

I created a sample package listener application which get launched when user clicks any other application. But currently I am not able to uninstall old version and even not able install updated version. The application is not allowing me to open settings or task manager or anything else. i am not able to do anything Please help me out. My phone get hacked by the application.

Is there any way to uninstall application?

Comment: What do you mean by urgent ? Vad Title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) to uninstall your application. Connect your device to your computer, and execute the following command from a terminal or command prompt:

```
adb uninstall <package name>
```

(Assuming you have Android SDK installed and adb is in the application PATH)